# plotstft() plotting short time fast fourier transform

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Here is my code:

```
>  from scipy.fftpack import fft 
>  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
>  from numpy.lib import stride_tricks 
>  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>  plotstft(sound_files["jazz"]["wavedata"],sound_files["jazz"]["samplerate"])
```

And it gives an error : "NameError: name 'plotstft' is not defined". How can I fix it? I am using python2.7 on ubuntu

Comment: What is `plotstft` and why do you expect it to be defined?

Comment: I am trying to perfom some audio processing exercises in the following link. In that link, it uses a function which is plotstft() under the fast fourier transform header. I think this function works under the matplotlib library but I am not sure.          http://www.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~schindler/lectures/MIR_Feature_Extraction.html

Comment: [Some utility functions are defined at the bottom of the page you linked](http://www.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/~schindler/lectures/MIR_Feature_Extraction.html#Utility-Functions). Among these is also the definition of plotstft. You will need to either copy them into your Python script or put them into another .py file and import from there.

Comment: Tahnk you my friend. You saved my time.